# Cannot install extensions in Visual Studio Code, no drop down recommendations

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

When I try and install an extension in VS Code, nothing happens, and there is no dropdown with recommendations as I type. The bar at the top just has a blue line that perpetually goes from left to right and eventually just closes.

This is on my work computer, would there be a domain restriction that prevents me from installing extensions? Are there alternative ways to install extensions?

[image]

Edit: Is there any way to view event logs for VS Code, so see whats happening?